# preplog.exe ran in foreach log file

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with x amount of web log files and I need to prep them for bulk import to SQL
for that I have to run preplog.exe into each one of them.
I want to create a Power script to do this for me, the problem that I'm having is that preplog.exe has to be run in CMD and I need to enter the input path and the output path.
For Example:

D:>preplog c:\blah.log > out.log

I've been playing with Foreach but I haven't have any luck.

Any pointers will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would guess...

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder\MyLogFiles" | Foreach-Object { preplog $_.FullName | Out-File "preplog.log" -Append }
```

FYI it is good practice on this site to post your not working code so at least we have some context. Here I assume you're logging to the current directory into one file.

Additionally you've said you need to run in CMD but you've tagged PowerShell - it pays to be specific. I've assumed PowerShell because it's a LOT easier to script.

I've also had to assume that the folder contains ONLY your log files, otherwise you will need to include a Where statement to filter the items.

In short I've made a lot of assumptions that means this may not be an accurate answer, so keep all this in mind for your next question =)

Comment: thanks for the feedback point taken. Yes i want to call the exe from powershell bit it has to be ran in a specific way. i do it from cmd like this. preplog.exe source log location > destination log location.

Comment: Get-ChildItem $DestinationPath | ForEach-Object {start-process $prep $_.fullname > $outprep}  It looks like its running but it takes more than 10 minutes and at the end it creates an empty .log file. ran from cmd it takes 3 seconds

Comment: 3 seconds per file? And I don't believe the `>` character appends to the file so it probably overwrote everything with a blank line. Use the style I gave you to output to a file, it's better practice.